# Bundle Price shows different on list page vs. product page.

Tags: magento-1.9, product, bundled-product

I have a dynamically priced Bundle Product.

It's composed of two products, product A ($10) and product B ($5).

They're part of the Bundle via a required checkbox where they're both selected by default.

On my product page, the output price for the Bundle Product is $15.

On my listing pages, the output price for the Bundle Product is $5.

Why is it displaying differently depending on the page?  I want for my listing page to also show $15.  Although I've tried changing /template/bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml, I'm wondering if I'm looking at the wrong file (the price on the product page seems to be changed via Javascript somehow, not sure).

Answer (score 0):

Magento has default feature of Bundle product price to show on the listing and product view page. It should be shown the min price on the listing page like,
Starting at $5 or as low as $5, and on the product page, the user can see the full price as there is the bundle.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Do you know if there's a way to change that?  I would like for the list page to show the same price as the product page, but I'm not sure how to go about that.  It seems like the product page price is being changed by Javascript (maybe from varien.js?) and I'm wondering if Magento has a way to get it to work for the listing page too (I just want the display prices to be consistent across my site, I think it's confusing for users to see the different prices showing).